# Getting python script to run only from folder with files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, path, xlsx

I have a python script which I would like to call csv and xlsx from a specific folder without having to specify the directory of each files needed to run the program.

```css
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("WindDirectionWest2.xlsx")
df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
hey=df["WindDirection"].mean()
print(int(hey))
df = pd.read_excel("WindDirectionSouth2.xlsx")
df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
he=df["WindDirection"].mean()
print(int(he))
df = pd.read_excel("WindDirectionEast2.xlsx")
df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
he=df["WindDirection"].mean()
print(int(he))
```

So, I would like to have a code in top of my script calling a folder which then makes it redundant to write each file path to each code.

P.s I do not know how to put the code as python. I can only see Javascript, CSS, and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = '/some/path/to/file'
for file in os.listdir(path):
     df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, file))
```

Comment: I will have to send the code to a third party and therefore I need a way to get the script running calling that specific folder without knowing the path it is stored on third party's engine. Does it make sense?
Unfortunately, your solution did not work quite well with my code.

Comment: haaaaa alright! i'll post another answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so, you can use "pkg_resources" module!
Your data file needs to be inside your package.

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.resource_filename('packageName', 'path/of/file/in/my/package.xlsx')
```

Comment: I get the following error: ValueError: Use of .. or absolute path in a resource path is not allowed.

Comment: what is your code ?